# Ask a limit question from George & Casella Example 1.5.4

Tags: limits, statistics

I have a question from George & Casella Example 1.5.4.

The cdf of the random variable X is $F_X(x) = 1-(1-p)^x$, x=1,2,...

The textbook claims that if $0<p<1$, then $\lim_{x\to -\infty} F_X(x)=0$.

I am confused here. I google the figure such as $0.3^x, 0.7^x$, and I find when x is going to negative infinity, it tends to positive infinity. Then I find  $\lim_{x\to -\infty} F_X(x)=-\infty$.

Comment: The formula for $F_X(x)$ is not supposed to be valid for all $x$. For any CDF we have $F_X(x) \to 0$ as $x \to -\infty$.

Comment: @geetha290krm I know your second sentence. That's why when I let x goes to negative infinity, I didn't get that F goes to 0.

Comment: $F_X(x)=0$ for $x <0$, $ F_X(x)=1$ for $x \geq1$ It makes no sense to take limit of $1-(1-p)^{x}$ as $x \to \infty$ because $F_X(x)$ is not given by this formula when $x >1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they mean that for $x\le 0$ then $F$ is defined to be zero. The expression you have is the value of $F$ at natural numbers while for non-natural numbers $x>0$, $F(x)=F(n)$ where $n$ is the greatest natural number less than or equal to $x$. Finally, as $x\to\infty$ then I hope you agree that $(1-p)^x\to 0$ and so $F(x) \to 1$.

Comment: p is fixed between 0 and 1. We should view p as a constant.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I will edit my answer